# A confusion in the representation of states in $k$-space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, crystals

In the book "*Introduction to Quantum Mechanics*" by Griffiths, chapter 5 section 3 (Solids), the author states the following:

> ...Each intersection point in $k$-space represents a distinct stationary state. Each block in this grid, and hence also each state, occupies an elementary volume in this space.

As I understood, there is one state for every point (intersection), but according the statement above it seems to me that there is one state for every block too! as indicated here:

[image]

Isn't this a contradiction?! It's quite evident to me that each block represents 8 states because it contains 8 points (vertices)!

So what did I miss?! any clarification please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each block contains 1/8 of 8 vertices, because each vertex also belongs to 8 blocks.

Comment: Aha!! it's similar to the counting of atoms in the cubic Bravais lattice! I got it, thank you so much!!

Comment: @Mr.Weathers I know it's been a few years, but could someone maybe expand on this? I still don't see that there is a 1 to 1 correspondence between blocks and vertices.